Get class from constant
I have a function with a parameter that is fed a constant.
The constant can come from several classes, see example:
function myFunction($const): string {
    // do some stuff
    // use the classname do some other stuff
    // do some more stuff

    return $output;
}

echo myFunction(SomeClass::A_CONSTANT);
echo myFunction(OtherClass::ALSO_A_CONSTANT);

To make things more difficult, the constants I'm getting come from aliased classes, in the class file outside the class you have something like this:
class_alias(RealClass::class, 'SomeClass');

Is there a way to get the classname from the constant?
So from the example above I would get RealClass when I use the constant SomeClass::A_CONSTANT.
I can work around the alias, getting SomeClass when I use SomeClass::A_CONSTANT is just fine.
I've tried get_defined_constants(), get_class(), get_parent_class() & get_called_class(), but those just get the result or result in errors due to not being in scope or the variable being a string instead of an object.

You may need to look at what you are trying to do and change that rather than trying to get some information from a constant value.

You're not passing in the class to you function. You're only passing in the value of the class constant, so the function has no clue where it came from. If you explain what it is you're trying to do (why you need it), we might be able to help. Right now, the question seem to be a XY problem.

The classname represents an external service, within myFunction() I need to call that service and get some information back. The "easiest" solution would be to add a parameter $service to myFunction() but that would mean I have to change a lot of code to add it and it makes the function much less flexible then using something like $service = getClassFromConst(SomeClass::A_CONSTANT);

Just to be clear, you don’t have a function that is fed a constant, you have a function with a single parameter of type string (or int or whatever). You can feed a constant into the function, or you can feed a literal, or you can chain a function’s return into it, or even a field on an object.

I’m not saying this is your code, but I’ve seen people wanting to do something similar for routing registering to avoid static methods, but as noted, the information is lost so this doesn’t work. That said, if you have a need to be aware of both a value and the class holding it, that’s maybe a good case for an Enum. You say you’d have to change a lot of code, so presumably this is already working and maybe you can just “upgrade” your function with a union type.
